# strange behavior in my statistics php script

Tags: php, logging, ip

i ve just created a website, where in the admin panel there is a statsitics module that is very important, and that recognize if an user visit the website for the first time (**unique**) or has already visit the website (**raw**).

to recognize if the user is unique or not, the script check if the ip is the same or if a cookie exist (on the same day).

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE['c'] ) && !empty( $_COOKIE['c'] ) && ctype_alnum( $_COOKIE['c'] ) ) { 
$cookie = secure_field( $_COOKIE['c'] ); } else { $cookie = NULL; }

$res = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE ( ip = '$ip' OR id = '$cookie' ) 
AND DATE_FORMAT( datetime, '%d.%m.%y' ) = DATE_FORMAT( now(), '%d.%m.%y' ) 
ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1" );

if( mysqli_num_rows( $res ) == 0 ) { $unique = 1; } else { $unique = 0; }
```

with me this script work perfectly (i've try with many browser, deleting cookie, change IP,..). But now i ve just see a strange behavior with an user, that use the same IP but all it's visits are registred as UNIQUE!

here the registred records (i've masked the ip for privacy):

```
2013-09-09 06:06:05 unique  112.201.***.*** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K...
2013-09-09 06:06:14 unique  112.201.***.*** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K...
2013-09-09 06:11:58 unique  112.201.***.*** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K...
2013-09-09 06:14:11 unique  112.201.***.*** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K...
2013-09-09 06:17:05 unique  112.201.***.*** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K...
2013-09-09 06:17:15 unique  112.201.***.*** Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K..
```

How is that possibile? and how i can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You never set `$res` so `mysqli_num_rows` should produce a warning and result in `false` which is equal to `0`. therefore the requests will always be unique.

this should work if you insert the ip properly and the sql is correct:

```
$res = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE ( ip = '$ip' OR id = '$cookie' ) 
AND DATE_FORMAT( datetime, '%d.%m.%y' ) = DATE_FORMAT( now(), '%d.%m.%y' ) 
ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1" );

if( mysqli_num_rows( $res ) == 0 ) { $unique = 1; } else { $unique = 0; }
```

also:
do you actually insert the ip into the table?

have you checked the query manually in phpmyadmin? does that work?

Comment: sorry, the '$res' there is in the script (i have just edit the post). Yes everything work perfectly in my test and also for every users, except for that one.. i really don't understand how it's possibile!!!

Comment: if its just a single user, the only possibility is that he has cookies blocked and your sql check for ip isnt working (because the ip is obviously the same) and every other user is identified by cookie. what you have to do: check if the sql table is filled correctly and test the query in phpmyadmin

Comment: thx for your help, but i'm pretty sure that both cookie and ip checks work fine, i just tryed to delete my cookies and i was registred as RAW via IP. bho, it's nonsense!